# How to Use Javascript in Hackerrank and Hackerearth?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a newbie to competitive programming. The only language I know is Javascript but if I select javascript option I couldn't even understand how to get input and how to print output in both the sites for some problems is Hackerrank the code looks like this

```
function processData(input) {
//Enter your code here
} 
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("ascii");
_input = "";
process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
  _input += input;
});

process.stdin.on("end", function () {
  processData(_input);
});
```

And in the same **Hackerrank** for some problems the initial code looks like this

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('ascii');

var input_stdin = "";
var input_stdin_array = "";
var input_currentline = 0;

process.stdin.on('data', function (data) {
 input_stdin += data;
});

process.stdin.on('end', function () {
  input_stdin_array = input_stdin.split("\n");
 main();    
});

function readLine() {
  return input_stdin_array[input_currentline++];
}

/////////////// ignore above this line ////////////////////

function main() {
  var n = parseInt(readLine());
}
```

Whereas in **Hackerearth** the initial code look like this

```
   function main(input) {
        //Enter your code here
        process.stdout.write("Hello World!");
    }
    
    process.stdin.resume();
    process.stdin.setEncoding("utf-8");
    var stdin_input = "";
    
    process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
        stdin_input += input;
    });
    
    process.stdin.on("end", function () {
       main(stdin_input);
    });
```

If someone gives me an example of a program how to get the inputs and print output in those sites or any solved program of those sites using javascript also will do I guess.

Comment: Maybe you should read the documentation on those sites? Just a thought. Since you tagged this with `node.js` you might want to read the documentation there also. Just sayin.

Comment: @kannucodert14 Would you update me if the solution I  provided helped? It would have helped on hackerearth for sure and hackerrank should not be much different?

Comment: @PankajShukla tomorrow i will check and update you bro. Thanks

Comment: @gforce301 Am always lazy to read the documentation dude

Comment: I don't think it's you - Hackerrank seems to be terrible for JavaScript.  The site seems to require a lot of extra junk that a programmer doesn't normally have to program to solve the problem!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Let's take a simple example from HackerEarth:
https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/input-output/basics-of-input-output/practice-problems/algorithm/find-factorial/

To provide the solution, you need to do this:

```
function main(input) {
    //Enter your code here
    var num = parseInt(input, 10);//This line expects input to be a string so convert to an int as per problem
    var res=1;
    for(var i=num;i>1;i--) {
        res *= i; 
    }
    process.stdout.write(res);//This is how you write output.
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is how you could do it in hackerrank:

```
function main() {
    var n = parseInt(readLine());
    var strN = n.toString();//<-- Convert int n to string
    for(var i=1;i<=10;i++) {
        process.stdout.write(strN+" x "+i+" = "+n*i);//<-- formatting the 
                                                     //question requires
        process.stdout.write("\n");//<-- newline
    }
}
```

The difference seems to be that in HackerRank, you need to convert the output to string yourself.
Hope it helps!

**EDIT2**:

For multiline input like:

```
5 1
1 2 3 4 1
```

You can do this:

```
function main(input) {
    //Enter your code here
    var data = input.split('\n');
    var firstLine = data[0].split(' ');
    var len = firstLine[0];
    //process.stdout.write('length:'+len);
    var toFind = firstLine[1];
    //process.stdout.write('toFind:'+toFind);
    //process.stdout.write('\n');
    var arr = data[1].split(' '); 
    //process.stdout.write(arr);
    for(var i=len-1;i>=0;i--) {
        if(arr[i] == toFind){
            process.stdout.write(i+1);
            return;
        }
    }
    process.stdout.write(-1);
}
```

Notice that input is multi-line, so first you need to split it into lines by doing `var data = input.split('\n');`.
Each split will give you string with spaces in between. So, to get individual characters, you have to split again but this time with space like `var firstLine = data[0].split(' ');`.
Once you have all the input, you are left with writing your own algorithm.
Notice that I have left comments too so that you know how to debug in the editor itself.

By the way this solution also works and is an accepted solution.

Hope this helps too!

Comment: Hi Bro that works perfectly on hackerearth whereas in hackerrank it doesn't take this one as an example problem https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-loops now here if i try to print like this process.stdout.write(n); it displays no output whereas if write process.stdout.write("hi"+n); it prints hi2 i thought the output will take only string so i converted into res=n.toString() and i tried to write even it didnt work any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Above solution for the problem you gave link for is working in HackerRank as well. Did you try?

Comment: Yes bro indeed it works solved other problems too in HackerRank but there is a problem in Hackerearth how can i get if it is more than 2 inputs for example https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/searching/linear-search/tutorial/ this problem if it is in C i will just do scanf("%d,",N) and scanf("%d,",M) to get the inputs whereas in JS i can get one input only on that problem

Comment: I have added another edit to help you further. Take a look!

Comment: Thanks allot for helping me out brother thanks for your patience what i did is i just get the first input alone i just loop over it and will split based on that. Thanks once again

Comment: the elements are string inside array. For example if I have to do find min or max, it won't return the desired result. Need to do parseInt as well on them. Can do a map on them 
`data[0].split(' ').map(function(item) {
    return parseInt(item, 10);
});`

Comment: @PankajShukla Are you still active here?

Answer (score 7):

## Let's take a simple example from HackerEarth:

https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/input-output/basics-of-input-output/tutorial/

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("utf-8");
var stdin_input = "";
process.stdin.on("data",function(input){
    stdin_input += input;
});
process.stdin.on("end",function (){
    main(stdin_input);
});
function main(input){
    var data = input.split('\n');
    var num = parseInt(data[0],10);
    var str = data[1];
    process.stdout.write(num *2 + "\n" + data[1]);
    

}
```

sample input:

5

helloworld

sample output:

10

helloworld

first we read the input in the form of string then we convert into array with and assign to new variable data and these look like ["5", "helloworld"]

Answer (score 7):

```
function main(input) {
let [first, second] = [...input.split("\n")];

 // do what ever you want here with inputs.
}
```

As Simple as that :) Happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

```
// Sample code to perform I/O:

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("utf-8");
var stdin_input = "";

process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
    stdin_input += input;                               // Reading input from STDIN
});

process.stdin.on("end", function () {
   main(stdin_input);
});

function main(input) {
    var data = input.split('\n');
    var firstLine = data[0].split(' ');
    var secondLine = (data[1].split(' '));
    let arr = [];
    for(let i=0;i<secondLine.length;i++){
        arr.push(parseInt(secondLine[i]));
    }
    findMininimum(arr);
    //process.stdout.write("Hi, " + input + ".\n");       // Writing output to STDOUT
}

// Warning: Printing unwanted or ill-formatted data to output will cause the test cases to fail


// Write your code here
function findMininimum(input){
console.log(Math.min(...input));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was recently stuck with the same kind of problem and have solved it using like this, hopefully it helps:

PS: Uncomment what is commented in the editor. After that add this:

```js
/*Generally the Question Format is in
2       //TestCases
3       //N
1 3 5   //Array
5
3 6 11 22 12
*/

/*
Javascript accepts only string hence you need to parse it into integers and break the input lines
*/

function solve(arr){
  //Code Here
}

 function main(input){
   var data = input.split('\n');    //split based on line
   var t = parseInt(data[0],split(' '));  //based on space
   var ind=0;
   while(ind<t){
     var n = parseInt(data[2*ind+1].split(' '));
     for(let i=0;i<n;i++){
       var val = data[2*ind+2].split(' ');
       var arr=[];
       for(let j=0;j<val.length;j++){
         arr.push(parseInt(val[j]));
       }
     }
     console.log(solve(arr));
     ind++;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `process.stdout.write` at end of `main` as needed like so:

```
function myFunction(input) {
//Enter your code here
}
function main() {
//stuff
process.stdout.write(myFunction(input))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Handling 2D Array Input in NodeJs in Hackerearth**

```
// Sample code to perform I/O:

// input we are taking
// 2                                        no. of test cases
// 3                                        2D array size
// 1 2 3
// 4 5 6
// 7 8 9
// 2                                        2D array size
// 4 3
// 1 4

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("utf-8");
var stdin_input = "";

process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
    stdin_input = input.split("\n");                               // Reading input from STDIN and splitting it
});

// now the stdin_input will contain
// stdin_input = ['2', '3', '1 2 3', '4 5 6', '7 8 9', '2', '4 3', '1 4']

process.stdin.on("end", function () {
   main(stdin_input);
});
function main(input) {
    let t =parseInt(input[0]) //string -> integer | no. of test cases
    let index = 1   // we have already consumed 0th index value so we are starting from 1
    while(t--){
        // we need to increase index value each time when we consume input
        n = parseInt(input[index])
        index++
        let arr= []
        for(let i=0;i<n;i++){
            arr.push([])
            temp = input[index].split(" ")
            for(let j=0;j<n;j++){                
               arr[i].push(parseInt(temp[j]))
            }
            index++
            process.stdout.write(arr[i].toString()); // we can only print string
            process.stdout.write("\n");
        }
      
      
        // write you logic here 
      
      
        process.stdout.write("------\n");
          
    }

        
}

// output
// 1,2,3
// 4,5,6
// 7,8,9
// ------
// 4,3
// 1,4
// ------
```

Comment: Please read the question carefully and add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
process.stdin.resume(); // A Readable Stream that points to a standard input stream (stdin)
process.stdin.setEncoding("utf-8"); // so that the input doesn't transform

let inputString1 = "";
let inputString = "";
let currentLine = 0;

process.stdin.on("data", function (userInput) {
  inputString1 = inputString1 + userInput; // taking the input string
});

process.stdin.on("end", function (x) {
  inputString1.trim();
  inputString1 = inputString1.split("\n"); // end line

  for (let i = 0; i < inputString1.length; i++) {
    inputString += inputString1[i].trim() + " ";
  }
  inputString = inputString.split(" ");

  main();
});

function readline() {
  let result = inputString[currentLine++];
  return parseInt(result); // change when you want to use strings, according to the problem
}

// ---------------------------------------------

// use readline() to read individual integers/strings
function main() {
  let t = readline();
  for (let i = 0; i < t; i++) {
    let n = readline();
    let arr1 = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
      arr1[i] = readline();
    }
    console.log(n,arr1)
  }
}
```

**This is for taking input where number of testcase are given **
2
2
2 4
3
1 2 3