# How do I use process.stdout with two parameters

Tags: javascript, stdout

I am taking a javascript assessment that requires me to use process.stdout rather than console.log and am confused on how to go about taking in two parameters.

For instance a question (that is similar to the one that I am asked, but I won't ask that specific question for fairness) is when giving a list of numbers and a second parameter number, n. Print out all the values up until the nth + 1 index (including n, not including n+1).

For a regular console log statement this would be a piece of cake:

```
function foo(list,n){
    for(let i=0;i<=n;i++){
      console.log(list[i] + "\n");
   }
}

foo([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],3);

// 1
// 2 
// 3
// 4
```

But I'm not sure how to parse the input

```
The question gives me this to work with:
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

var stdin = '';
process.stdin.on('data', function () {
}).on('end', function() {
});
```

Comment: Is your question about how to write to stdout? Or how to read from stdin? Or both?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528075/how-to-use-javascript-in-hackerrank-and-hackerearth might help.